# How does 'containment' in draggable widget work

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/M5JZy/3/) jsfiddle

What I'm trying to do here is to show an image through a parent div.

```
<div id="main">
    <img src="http://....">
</div>
```

the parent element is smaller than the image and has on overflow set to hidden. 
To drag the image around I'm using the [Draggable widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) from jQuery UI.

I want to be able to show the whole image by dragging it around, but I don't want to see the background color of #main. So I should not be able to drag the image to far into on direction.
I think this can be done using the 'containment' property, but I cannot get this to work.

For example, if #main is 200 x 200 and the image is 300x300, I would say it should look something like this

```
$(img).draggable({containment: [0,0,-100,-100]});
```

Any suggestions why the jsfiddle doesn't work and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to account for the container's width, position, border and the image dimensions.

```
var img = $('img'), 
    pos = { offset: $('#main').offset(), 
            height: $('#main').height(), 
            width: $('#main').width() 
    };
img.draggable({ 
    containment: [
        pos.offset.left + pos.width + 1 - img.width(), 
        pos.offset.top + pos.height + 1 - img.height(), 
        pos.offset.left + 1, 
        pos.offset.top + 1 ]
});
```

[Here is an updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/M5JZy/4/)